# WooCommerce add to cart short code not working

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Yesterday I tried to implement an add to cart button outside of product page 
So I tried this short code

> [add_to_cart id=”#″ sku=”#″]

It was working fine so today I dicid to go ahead and do this on live, but for some reason that I ignore it doesn't work either on test or live site.

There is an empty space where the button is supposed to be.

Nothing has been changed or add since last night to the site

I'm running WooCommerce Version 2.6.9 and WP Version 4.7

[image]

Comment: are you added in WYSIWYG??

Comment: no Im not using any WYSIWYG

Comment: I mean to say where you use this short-code??

Comment: http://yourwebdesignshop.com.au/woocommerce-tutorial-how-to-insert-a-add-to-cart-button-outside-of-a-product-page/

Comment: on none product pages Like the front page
I want the user to add the product to cart without having to go to product page

Comment: that's what I try to use, it was working perfectly last night

Comment: You don't have that button???

Comment: I have hack if you like :WooCommerce Shortcodes plugin

Comment: don't have no, I just copy the code and it was working

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-shortcodes/screenshots/

Comment: you mean its working now.

Comment: i will try this pluging and see how it goes

Comment: please provide url

Comment: Lets try new thing

Comment: its post or page??

Comment: it's a page. but
if there is other solution to add this button im open for suggestion

Comment: do you know custom page templete??

Comment: but why should i create a custom page template ?

Comment: product is avaliable that [add_to_cart id=”#″]

Comment: yes they are all available and I try with all products id but still nothing is displayed

Comment: instead of addtocard just display product on page

Comment: hello are you added a shortcode for display product??

Comment: yes it's added aleady

Comment: product not show at that page.Nothing working

Comment: please check plugin if you are install after yesterday change s

Answer (score 0):

Please check the screenshot below....
[image: Follow this screenshot]

Comment: for some reason I dont know why I do not have this icon on my edit page

Comment: Could you please update the woocommerce? So I think it'll work.

Comment: okay, try with this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Comment: already installed and in use 
it generate the same code and the result is the same...nothing

Answer (score 0):

**Case for not showing button**

- A Product stock and visibilty of button check.
- A CSS issue
- A function.php customization.
- Please check with page

**Solution**

- Compare with official document
  https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/
- If you haven't shortcode button in WYIWYG editor then install following plugin
  https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-shortcodes/screenshots/

Comment: nothing works, everything looks fine (css php js) product is visible and available
on product page everything is working fine but on none products the button is not visible and the <code></code> is empty which means it has not been generated

Comment: what are you trying to say...you just that its wokring

Comment: did you installed plugin?

Comment: please provide url of site here

Comment: excuse me for 15 minute.I will be back.

Comment: remove test at the end

Comment: in which section addtocart is added